# How to obtain channel guide category of a youtube channel

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to obtain the guide categories using two different approaches non of which are working for me.

Approach 1: To call  the guideCategories API passing a guide category id and then checking to see if the result contains the channel id and repeating the call for the 10-12 Youtube guide categories available.

For example, this call is supposed to return all channels that belong to the **Music** channel guide category (id=`GCTXVzaWM`)

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/guideCategories?part=snippet&key={MyAPIKey}&id=GCTXVzaWM](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/guideCategories?part=snippet&key=%7BMyAPIKey%7D&id=GCTXVzaWM)

However, the response contains only one channel information: the **YouTube Spotlight** channel.

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#guideCategoryListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/nJlbZCXF0fN7Tnv7p0aM65jh5Fw\"",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#guideCategory",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/mbUaBJAZzQQXrUy_F02c8idvkek\"",
   "id": "GCTXVzaWM",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Music"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Why aren't other music channels listed in this response? For example the following channel named **Music** (channel id=`UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ`) is a music channel but it is not returned in this response. why?

Approach 2: Obtain the guide category information from the channels API call by passing the channel id.

For example here is the call I am using to get the category ID for the channel above (channel id=`UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ`). But when I make the call and look at the result I do not see any guide category information even though I requested every information available from this API as shown below:

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,contentDetails,topicDetails,contentOwnerDetails,brandingSettings,localizations,status,contentOwnerDetails,statistics,invideoPromotion&key={MyAPIKey}&id=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,contentDetails,topicDetails,contentOwnerDetails,brandingSettings,localizations,status,contentOwnerDetails,statistics,invideoPromotion&key=%7BMyAPIKey%7D&id=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ)

The response doesn't have any guide category information including the **Music** guide category (id=`GCTXVzaWM`).

Please help!

Thanks
T

Comment: Note that as of September 9, 2020, [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [GuideCategories: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories/list) is deprecated.